# How can I typeorm update column value

Tags: typeorm

```
UPDATE 'table' 
SET 'Column' = 'Column' - 30 
WHERE 'ID' = 1;
```

```
async update(ID: number, value: number) {
    await this.Repository.update({ID}, { ? ? ?})
}
```

May I know how to use SQL like above?

Should I use typeorm query builder?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

solution 1:

```
const isEntityFound = await this.repository.findOne(ID);
const decrement: number = 30
  if (isEntityFound) {
        isEntityFound.Column -= decrement;
        await this.repository.save(isEntityFound);
  }
```

solution 2:

```
async update(ID: number) {
    const decrement: number = 30
    await this.Repository.createQueryBuilder()
        .update(table)
        .set({ Column: () => `Column - ${decrement}` })
        .where("ID = :idParam", { idParam: ID })
        .execute();
}
```